# Handling git repos developing one out of another preserving history

Tags: git, gitlab

community!
I am not a proper programmer I program more or less for a hobby.
Is there a way relate two git repositories, when one is developped out of another one, so that I can see their relation with `git log` or `git graph`?

My workflow is as follows:
I work on a project in an IDE or Editor and then there comes an idea to my mind or a request for another project and I admit that instead of opening a new window or creating new folders, I open new (temporary) files in the repo I am working; this is I am working on two projects in parallel. Later, when cleaning up the thing, I want to separate the projects in terms of split repos.

What I do normally is take the files/folders not belonging to the old project A, move them to a branch and clone this branch to a new project/repo B. Thus I preserve the history which I can filter out with the according commands - this is, what I solved so far.

When I look at the `log`, there's the history of my files depending on how much I cleaned history, but there is no relation from repo B to repo A.

Of course I read about `submodules`and `subtrees` as well as about remotes but none of them fits my needs, since the repos don't have necessarily a relation in terms of code or software but the relation is more for me to see, what I have developed while working on other projects, so the relation should be kept for archival reasons.

I hope, I made clear what I want to achieve, maybe you have some hints or suggestions for me, where to look or read further. If there is information missing, I am willing to deliver it.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do this.... you are working on your project located in `~/projects/projectA` (a git repo). Then you get a request to start another project..... and say you want to put it in `~/projects/projectB`, from projectA's `some-branch`... you could do this:

```
cd ~/projects
git clone -b some-branch projectA projectB # only clone that branch into projectB
```

That way you keep the full story of some-branch in projectB.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

My fault that I did not make it clear that this is what I do usually - sorry about that.

After your answer, I took a look at an example-project with `git log --graph --oneline` and of course what I see is a linear graph when cloning a branch.

I guess my problem goes beyond the scope of a repo; I want something that can show me, which project (or repo) follows on which

`projectA some-branch -> projectB`

(it's not by chance, that this looks a bit like dot-language)

Comment: Repo's where a branch came from are not tracked by git. It's all about branches.... even more than branches, it's all about **revisions**.